# invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

This is the script function that is causing problems:

```
def crawl feedbacks, source, project_id, url, use_spam_filter
    @logger.info url
    xml = open(url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(xml, nil, 'UTF-8')
    doc.xpath("//entry").each do |entry|
      title = entry.at("./title").content
      content = entry.at("./content").content
      content.force_encoding('UTF-8')
      content = content.gsub(/[^0-9a-z ]/i, '')

      language = @language_detector.detect(content)
      if language != 'en'
        puts "#{language}: #{title}"
        next
      end

      if use_spam_filter && @spam_filter.is_spam?(content)
        puts "spam: #{title}"
        next
      end

      #content = strip_invalid_utf8_chars(content)

      puts "encoding: #{content.encoding.name }"
      polarity, description = @sentiment_classifier.process(content)
      published = Time.zone.parse(entry.at("./published").content)
      link = entry.at("./link[@rel='alternate']")["href"]
      author_image = entry.at("./link[@rel='image']")["href"] rescue nil
      author_name = entry.at("./author/name").content
      author_url = entry.at("./author/uri").content

      if source == Feedback::BLOG && @url_filter.should_ignore(link)
        puts "urlfilter: #{title}"
        next
      elsif source == Feedback::TWITTER && @author_filter.should_ignore(author_name)
        puts "authorfilter: #{title}"
        next
      end

      feedbacks << [project_id, published, title, description, link, polarity, author_image, author_name, author_url, source, project_id.to_s + link]
    end
rescue Exception => e
    puts e
    puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
    @logger.info e.message
    @logger.info e.backtrace.join("\n")
  end
```

I get the invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 error whenever the crawler is parsing the following urls:

http://blogsearch.google.com/blogsearch_feeds?hl=en&q=%22Goodyear%22&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=atom&as_oq=goodyear+tires

and

http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=Goodyear&rpp=100&phrase=goodyear+tires

The content.encoding.name always shows UTF-8, but I just can't figure out why i get the error

Comment: Heh, Google 403'd my `wget(1)` attempt on the first URL. Be careful. :)

Comment: The function actually works for the first few entities, but as it parses along the XML it reaches a point where it triggers the error. I'm not so sure if it's because of a 403

Comment: it was more a reminder to pay attention to [5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS).

Comment: Yeah I should probably start reading those rules before things can get wrong. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Incidentally, my `isutf8(1)` tool found no problems in the twitter search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comtability problem had to reinstall the newest version of Nokogiri